# Search Numpy array with multiple values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have numpy 2d array having duplicate values.

I am searching the array like this.

```
In [104]: import numpy as np

In [105]: array = np.array

In [106]: a = array([[1, 2, 3],
     ...:            [1, 2, 3],
     ...:            [2, 5, 6],
     ...:            [3, 8, 9],
     ...:            [4, 8, 9],
     ...:            [4, 2, 3],
     ...:            [5, 2, 3])

In [107]: num_list = [1, 4, 5]

In [108]: for i in num_list :
     ...:     print(a[np.where(a[:,0] == num_list)])
     ...:
 [[1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
[[4 8 9]
 [4 2 3]]
[[5 2 3]]
```

The input is list having number similar to column 0 values.
The end result I want is the resulting rows in any format like array, list or tuple for example

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 8, 9],
       [4, 2, 3],
       [5, 2, 3]])
```

My code works fine but doesn't seem pythonic. Is there any better searching strategy with multiple values?

like `a[np.where(a[:,0] == l)]` where only one time lookup is done to get all the values.

my real array is large

Comment: sorry for long explanation. I posted similar question on code review but I failed to explain it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Using [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) -

```
a[np.in1d(a[:,0], num_list)]
```

**Approach #2 :** Using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
num_arr = np.sort(num_list) # Sort num_list and get as array

# Get indices of occurrences of first column in num_list
idx = np.searchsorted(num_arr, a[:,0])

# Take care of out of bounds cases
idx[idx==len(num_arr)] = 0 

out = a[a[:,0] == num_arr[idx]]
```

Comment: Sorry for changing the varialble l to num_list.

Comment: which one is in your opinion better? I am evaluating though for my case

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject If you have a large number elements in `num_list`, I would say `searchsorted` is worth a try.

Comment: `0.60s v 0.32s for in1d v searchsorted`

Comment: Approach #2 is useless for my case. I don't know but it doesn't give all the search.

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject Is `num_list` sorted?

Comment: nope. So I need to sort the input list first. let me try. It's working now. Thanks.

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject Edited to sort and convert an array in one go. Should give a bit more performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
a[numpy.in1d(a[:, 0], num_list), :]
```

Comment: I am new to numpy syntax. What is last : is for?

Comment: It means "take everything". So `a[0, :]` is first row, `a[:, 0]` is first column etc.

Comment: Ok. I got confused as Diwakar has ommited : in his answer.