# Compare matrices in Python and store results

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I would like to compare a 70x1 matrix with a 1000x3 matrix. What i want to do is compare the first column of the second matrix with the first matrix, find all the common values and then store the results in a new third matrix which is going to have all 3 columns.

I used `np.intersect1d` to find the common values between the two matrices but that is about it.

I can't find a way to import the other two columns of the second matrix to the new one.

Matrix1

```
[1.0

4.7

4.8

4.9

5.0

5.1]
```

Matrix2

```
[[3.0, 1.8, -3.0]

[3.1, 2.2, -3.0]

[4.7, 2.4, -3.0]

[3.3, 2.8, -3.0]

[3.40, 3.0, -3.0]]
```

Matrix3

```
[4.7, 2.4, -3.0]
```

Comment: Sounds very close - https://stackoverflow.com/q/44921316

Comment: Can you post 1. valid python arrays and 2. the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.in1d`:

```
a = numpy.array([1.0,4.7,4.8,4.9,5.0,5.1])
b = numpy.array([
    [3.0, 1.8, -3.0],
    [3.1, 2.2, -3.0],
    [4.7, 2.4, -3.0],
    [3.3, 2.8, -3.0],
    [3.40, 3.0, -3.0]
])

c = b[numpy.in1d(b[:, 0], a), :]
# array([[ 4.7,  2.4, -3. ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the first column values of each matrix, convert to set, intersect and convert back to list (or `np.array`):

```py
matrix3 = list(set(y for x in matrix1[:,:1] for y in x) & set(y for x in matrix2[:,:1] for y in x))
```

Comment: i get an error 'too many indices for array'. i am sorry but i am quite new to coding

Comment: @Giomix88 because according to the representation of `matrix1` that you've posted, it is not a matrix but a 1D vector.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for numpy:

```
m1 = [1.0, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5.0, 5.1]
m2 = [[3.0, 1.8, -3.0],
[3.1, 2.2, -3.0],
[4.7, 2.4, -3.0],
[3.3, 2.8, -3.0],
[3.40, 3.0, -3.0]]

output = []
for value in m2:
    if value[0] in m1:
        output.append(value)

print(output)
```

Gives:

```
[[4.7, 2.4, -3.0]]
```